# get the text value of a select created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input, with have an event when you `keyup` four characters. the error happens when:

1. Add one row (have two)
2. in first row. Write four characters. The select fill with dummy options. select one option of select and write the text in input.
3. in second row. Write four characters. The select fill with dummy options. Select one option of select and write the **value** in input, and **I will the text**.

the problem is there

```
<select onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
```

How can I solve it? I want always the text value, and only put in the first row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var wrapper = $("#table-editable"); //Fields wrapper


$(".delete").on('click', function() {
 $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    $('.check_all').prop("checked", false); 
 check();
});

var i=1;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
 count=$('table tr').length;
    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td>";
    data +="<td><div class='select-editable'><select onchange='this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value' name='mytext' id='mytext"+i+"'><option value=''></option><option value='115x175 mm'>115x175 mm</option></select><input type='text' name='input' id='input"+(count)+"' value='' /></div></td></tr>";
 $('table').append(data);
 i++;
});

function select_all() {
 $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function(){ 
  if($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0){ 
   $(this).prop("checked", false); 
  } else {
   $(this).prop("checked", true); 
  } 
 });
}

function check(){
 obj=$('table tr').find('span');
 $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
 id=value.id;
 $('#'+id).html(key+1);
 });
 };
  
   wrapper.on('keypress', 'input', function () {
      var cs = $(this).val().length+1;
      console.log( "total caracters:" + cs, $(this));
       $(this).prev().html('<option value="1">dummy01</option><option value="2">dummy02</option><option value="3">dummy03</option>')
    });
  
});
```

```css
 .select-editable {
   position: relative;
   background-color: white;
   border: solid grey 1px;
   width: 350px;
   height: 18px;
 }
 
 .select-editable select {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   font-size: 14px;
   border: none;
   width: 350px;
   margin: 0;
 }
 
 .select-editable input {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 330px;
   padding: 1px;
   font-size: 12px;
   border: none;
 }
 
 .select-editable select:focus,
 .select-editable input:focus {
   outline: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='students' method='post' name='students' action='index.php'>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" id="table-editable">
  <tr>
    <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
    <th>S. No</th>
    <th>First Name</th>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
    <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
    <td>  
    <div class="select-editable">
      <select onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text" name="mytext" id="mytext">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
        <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
        <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="input" id="input1" value="" />
      </div>
  </td>   

</table>

<button type="button" class='delete'>- Delete</button>
<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add More</button>
<p>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' class='but'/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: its `textContent` not a `text`

Answer (score 0):

I'l respond mostly on the title of your question.  Not sure if it solves everything, but it looks like you could use this answer.

The on() method permits you to do do the following: $(container).on(event, child_notes, function(){ ... })

Those child_notes can be dynamically pushed data.

example:

```
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myselect').on('click', 'option', function(e) {
        var message = ' clicked on: ' + $(this).html() ;
        $('#log').html(message);
      });
    });
    function fill_select() {
      var options = ['apple', 'lemon', 'banana'];
      var innerHtml = '';
      for(var i in options) {
        innerHtml += '<option value="'+ i +'">'+ options[i] +'</option> ';
      }
      $('#myselect').html(innerHtml);        
    }
  </script>
  <select id="myselect" name="fruit"></select>
  <br/>
  Click button to fill in the select: 
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="fill_select()"/>
  <p id="log"></p>
  <style>
    p {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 3px;
    }
  </style>
<body>
```

Comment: I dont need charge a select. Visualize de problem. "Run the code snipet" and create a new row. Firts row you push four characters and the select be fill with dummy list. You select and you see the text value. However if you do the same with the second row you have the select value intead text value

Answer (score 0):

solved.

I change  the code when generate dinamically the select. must change

onchange='this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value --> this.nextElementSibling.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text

in .js file